# Emacs Calc: What's the meaning behind the name `calc-roll-down`?

Tags: calc

In Emacs Calc I use `<TAB>` to swap the last two elements on the stack. The command for this is called `calc-roll-down`. What does "roll down" mean in this context?

When ***rolling*** the stack I would expect the whole stack rolls, but the default operation is just to ***swap*** the last two elements. (I know I can ***roll*** the stack with the same command (via `C-u 0 <TAB>`), but it is not the default operation of the command.)

Do I miss something here?

Comment: Why that name was given I don't know, and maybe no one knows. Is that really what you're asking?

Comment: Or are you really asking what "roll down" might mean in this context? If the latter, I'd guess it means to roll the top element down one, so it becomes second instead of first. If that's what it does, and that's what that name is meant to indicate, then perhaps it's not the best name. But it's shorter than explicitly saying which two are being swapped.

Comment: @Drew Yes, that’s what I’m asking!

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the [implementation](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/calc/calc-misc.el#n428) of `calc-roll-down`: it takes an argument `n`, but when called interactively with `TAB` that argument is nil. In that case, the function calls the subordinate function `calc-roll-down-stack` with an argument of 2, thereby exchanging the top two elements. But if you call it with a different argument `n` (e.g. `C-u TAB` would call it with a prefix argument of `'(4)` which the function interprets as 4), then the  top `n` elements of the stack are indeed rolled.

Comment: Aha, so the default operation is “roll 2”, which sort-off, kind-off makes sense…